# I want my axios query 1 is finish to execute my 2nd

Tags: reactjs, axios, request

I would like my "userid" to no longer be null for executing my 2nd request. the code is

```
const [userid, setUserid] = useState(null)

const userConnected = useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            try {
                const resp = await httpClient.get("//localhost:5000/@me");
                setUserid(resp.data.id)
                console.log(resp.data.id)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Not authenticated");
            }
        })();
    }, []);

const fetchUserItem = async () => {

    try {
        const owner = await axios({
            url: `${baseUrl}/additem/owner/${userid}`, //problem: 
//user.id = Null 
//so its like ${baseUrl}/additem/owner/null
            method: 'get'
        })
        const { events } = owner.data
        console.log(owner.data)
        setitemList(events)
    }
    catch {
        console.log('error')
    }
}
```

i think the problem is:
as the 2 requests are carried out at the same time the `{userid} = null` (usestate)
so I have `http://5000/additem/owner/null`
i must have `http://5000/additem/owner/12423`

Comment: maybe the solution is : put a if (userid = null) {//dont execute this request} but i dont know how to do that}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it, maybe this would work out:

```
const [userid, setUserid] = useState(null);

const userConnected = useEffect(() => {
  // to run below function only when userid is null
  userid == null
    ? (async () => {
        try {
          const resp = await httpClient.get("//localhost:5000/@me");
          setUserid(resp.data.id);
          console.log(resp.data.id);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("Not authenticated");
        }
      })()
    // call fetchUserItem inside useEffect
    : (async () => {
        await fetchUserItem();
      })();
}, [userid] /* define userid in dependency array */);
```